# Loopback Interface of Virtual Machine and Local Host

Tags: java, networking, udp, virtual-machine

I am new to working with Vitrual Machines and I was trying to find the answer to my networking problem. I am trying to send data from my VM to my local host in Java via my loopback interface but I am not receving packets throught the DatagramPackets API. I was wondering if the loopback interface of my VM and my local machine are seperate or if they are the same and already connected. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The loopback interface in your VM is completely separate from the loopback interface of your host.

Comment: Thats what I thought, I dont have internet connection but I need to send UDP packets between them, any thoughts?

Comment: Im using Hyper-V for my VM

Comment: It depends on your hypervisor provider.  Many of them can create special networks between just the host and vm.  Or you can statically assign an IP to your host, and send from the VM to that address.

Comment: Thanks Dave, i was able to create an Internal vSwitch than i had DHCP configure the IP automatically, which I then passed into my DatagramSocket object which was able to receive the data. Appreciate the help.